# I'm Need Help Adding My Paint Component to the Frame in a Class

Tags: java, class, hidden, paintcomponent

I need help making what I am trying to paint visible on the screen. I was able to set it up properly in the main, however I feel like it would be more organized to keep everything in their own classes. The window will show up, but nothing will be painted. Even the background I set does not show up.

```
public class CharacterCreator extends JPanel {

//Declare Variables

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon();

//PAINT
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);


    //Drawing Code
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawOval(10, 10, 10, 10);
}

//Window Creator
public CharacterCreator() {
    super();
    JFrame application = new JFrame();
    application.setTitle("Window");
    application.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    application.setIconImage(null);
    application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    application.setSize(500, 400);
    application.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    application.setVisible(true);


}
}
```

This is what the main looks like:

```
public class GameProject {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        JPanel CC = new CharacterCreator();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `CharacterCreator` to your `JFrame`:

```
application.add(this);
```

*Aside:* Consider using [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: Thank you very much @Reimeus, that fixed it. I also added the "setBackground(Color.WHITE);" to the paint component and that fixed the background issue. It's just been a very long time since I've done graphics and am trying to jog the memory again. Thanks again for the quick response. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of the Window Creator and implement this:

```
 public CharacterCreator() {
    super();
    JFrame application = new JFrame();
    application.setTitle("Window");
    application.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    application.setIconImage(null);
    application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    application.setSize(500, 400);
    application.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    application.setVisible(true);

    CharacterCreator panel = CharacterCreator();
    application.add(panel);
    }
```